# Java Caching System MaxLife vs MaxLifeSecond

Tags: java, jcs

I'm using Java Caching System (JCS - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/ )

I'd like to know the difference between MaxLife and MaxLifeSeconds

> MaxLife: If you specify that elements within a region are not eternal, then you can set the max life seconds. If this is exceeded the elements will be removed passively when a client tries to retrieve them. If you are using a memory shrinker, then the items can be removed actively.
>
> MaxLifeSeconds: If elements are not eternal, this option defines the maximum life of each object before it is removed. If the memory shrinker is running, objects are removed by the shrinker; if not, they are removed when they're accessed. This option defaults to -1, which disables the option.

These definitions seem nearly the same.

Is it just a change in name?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that MaxLifeSeconds is depricated.

With JCS  2.0-beta-1 I have:

```
    CacheAccess.getCacheControl().getElementAttributes().setMaxLife(arg0);
    CacheAccess.getCacheControl().getElementAttributes().getMaxLife();
```

And JCS documentation lists MaxLife as a Region (Element) Property

[JCS RegionProperties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/RegionProperties.html)

In an old mailing list archive (Thu, 11 May 2006 ) I find a reference to MaxLifeSeconds in a message about an upgrading to JCS version 1.2.7.0

[jakarta-jcs-users mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-jcs-users/200605.mbox/%3CB30C2483766F9342B6AEF108833CC84E06CA7C30@ecogenemld50.Org.Collegeboard.local%3E)